# Store score at the time of completing game & get data on HighScore button press in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have done this code to store score.

But this is giving me the last added score only, not storing data every time on new index.

```
-(IBAction)btnSaveScore:(id)sender
{
    if(!dictWinData)
        dictWinData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:txt_EnterName.text,
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",iTap], nil];

    int increment = 0;

    NSLog(@"array data is:--> %@",array);

    for (int intWinData = 1; intWinData < [array count]; intWinData++)
    {
        [dictWinData setObject:array forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NameScore%d",increment]];
        increment++;
    }
}
```

If any mistake is there in my code then please let me guide for this.

Is there anyother way to store the data..?

Is `NSUserDefaults` helpful to store & display data...?

How to use `NSUserDefaults` to store & retrive data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
int increment = 0;
```

Every time you press the save button the `increment` will be initialized to zero and hence every time the value is added to dictionary for same key `NameScore0`. Hence it will over write the existing dictionary value.

You need to make the `increment` as static like `static int increment = 0;` or make it as a global variable, it will solve the issue.

```
-(IBAction)btnSaveScore:(id)sender
{
    if(!dictWinData)
        dictWinData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:txt_EnterName.text,
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",iTap], nil];

    static int increment = 0;

    for (int intWinData = 1; intWinData < [array count]; intWinData++)
    {
        [dictWinData setObject:array forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NameScore%d",increment]];
        increment++;
    }
}
```

`NSUserDefaults` is used for displaying the application setting in the ios device's settings pane. Don't save your application data there.
Instead of `NSUserDefaults` you can use `plist` to store data.

Please check the [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuzKKr4frIM)

Comment: ....Thanks for the suggestion, Now it is working properly.....i am getting all records in the tabel....but once i close the application & then play again the score list gets empty...

Comment: @JoePatel: score list is geting empty because you are storing it in the memory (array), when the application is closed then it'll surely go off. You need to save it using plist or sqlite or core data. I have given a link in my answer, please check that too.

Comment: @JoePatel: please check my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581456/how-to-store-data-in-the-tableview-update-it-next-time/11583985#11583985